# Concatenate two char pointers with unknown sizes without using strings in arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino

First, let me tell you why I can't use strings - because my data length exceeds 2048 bytes

A simplified codes goes like this

```
char* pointerOne = "First part";
char* pointerTwo = "Seconds part";
```

I need to concatenate pointerOne and poniterTwo.
Length of pointerOne and pointerTwo changes.
Is there a way to get a single char array without hard coding a length?
I'm flexible to change to any data type.
I've tried using JSON data type, it worked but it was too slow for my required data rate.

Thank you.

Comment: Get the length of the strings, and allocate `length_of_first + lenght_of_second + 1` bytes to store the resulting string? Oh, and Arduino is usually programmed in C++, not C.

Comment: Is this what you want? `char* str = malloc(strlen(pointerOne) + strlen(pointerTwo) + 1), strcpy(str, pointerOne); strcat(pointerOne, pointerTwo);`

Comment: You can't concatenate pointers. What you are trying to do is to concatenate strings. `size_t newlen = strlen(pointerOne) + strlen(pointerTwo); char *newstr = malloc(newlen+1); if (newstr) sprintf(newstr, "%s%s", pointerOne, pointerTwo);`

Comment: `char* pointerOne = "First part";` should be `const char* pointerOne = "First part";`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the varying length you have to use dynamic memory and `realloc()` (**https://riptutorial.com/c/example/4329/reallocating-memory**) for concatentating the char arrays use `memcpy()` to concatenate the second part to the first part (after (re-)allocating enough memory , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm )

*Sentinel values* could be used to determine the length of the valid data (meaning where the first part and second part ends)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value